# When does Doctrine's postPersist event be called?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

From the Doctrine2 documentation:

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

I'm still in doubt about transactions, say that i have 5 persist operations to do in a transaction, does the `postPersist` event be called after every persist or just after the transaction commit?

Answer (score 1):

It is called for **every entity** that is inserted in the database.

Even for new entities that are persisted because of a cascade operation (set in your association with `cascade={"persist"}`) the `postPersist` event is fired.

The event is triggered [here in the `executeInserts` method in the `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1027), so literally for all inserts.

Comment: so i should make an event postFlush to this be called after a commit right?

Comment: that depends, what are you looking to do?

Comment: @jbrunoxd Hard to answer, like Jason said it depends on what you want to achieve...

Comment: @Wilt i need to calculate the distance between points and these points could be changed between the inserts from the entities, so i would only calculate them when all of them are inserted

Comment: @jbrunoxd Well, I would say you have all the information on `postPersist` that you need now to figure out how to do that. Otherwise I would suggest you ask new question with more details on your case...